# How to deal with Latitude Longitude errors of gps data while plotting on google map?

Tags: gps, nmea

Recently I am working to plot latitude and longitude of GPS data on Google Map. The latitude and longitude is in NMEA format and I have converted it in to compatible format to display on google map. I am able to plot the data on google map successfully. My data is supposed to be on a straight line but it goes zigzag like mountains. Is is the problem of GPS data not having accurate latitude and longitude? or the problem while converting the NMEA format data? How to fix these  kinds of errors if the GPS data is not 100% accurate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the quality of your GPS receiver (recreational, professional, survey, military, etc), the accuracy of your GPS solution can be different. Some receivers can track more GPS signals at different frequencies, and can have an access to DGPS information, etc.
For recreational GPS receivers the error level can be at the order of 10 meters. So my suggestion is if you know that uour solution is a straight line, you can do a least square parameter estimation to a linear function. That approach tend to smooth out error and you can get better solution.